# Create a policy that don't check a claim for Admin role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to build permission based authorization in ASP.NET Core 3.1.
I implemented policies in my `Startup.cs` but also I don't want to use custom requirements handler for all policies. Because my condition is simple. For example if the user has role `Admin` don't check and authorize, if user has `User` role then check relational claim at the Startup.cs for a policy.

I implemented at Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GetDefinition",
        policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "User")
                        .RequireClaim("CanGetDefinition"));
});
```

How can I skip checking a claim if the user has Admin role in a policy creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something based on [using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy):

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GetDefinition",
        policy => policy.RequireAssertion(
             (context) => {
                 return context.User.IsInRole("Admin") || 
                        (
                             context.User.IsInRole("User") && 
                             context.User.HasClaim(p => p.Type == "CanGetDefinition")
                        );
             }
});
```

Comment: Can you fix as context.User.HasClaim(p => p.Type == "CanGetDefinition") to clain check. Then this is correct solution

Comment: Done. Sorry for this, I did not check it live.